# When does an Entity Framework object dispose of its data?

Tags: entity-framework, garbage-collection

Say that I have the following code:

```
using (var db = new MyDatabaseContext())
{
    foreach (var entity in db.LargeEntities)
    {
        byte[] data = entity.LargeBlob;
        File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\" + entity.FileName);
    }
}
```

When will the data for each entity.LargeBlob be ready for garbage collection? During the loop? After the using statement? I'm done with the objects after the WriteAllBytes line, so I'd like it to be disposed as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ready for gc after the `Using` block. Because EF keeps a local copy of the loaded items you have to dispose Context to release the cached items.

Comment: Ok so to achieve earlier disposing I have to fetch the list of primary keys first, then iterate through it with the using statement inside the loop, right?

Comment: @Nilzor: You can possibly load the entities without tracking. In EF 4.1 this would be: `foreach (var entity in db.LargeEntities.AsNoTracking())`. In this case EF doesn't cache the entities in its context (at least if you don't have properties with lazy loading on the entity).